# I want to know the way django websites consume RAM or computer memory

Tags: python, django

I am about to develop a website. And, I expect to get a lot of traffic in it. It is in python (Django). I wonder if my web application uses 2 MB of RAM for one service(like if I run it in my PC directly in terminal, it consumes 2 MB of RAM) then if I get 1000 users on my website in a particular time, will my website need 2000 MB of RAM (2MB per user * 1000 users)? Does it go this way?

Answer (score 1):

To test that, and see what kind of increase in memory consumption you can expect, open a few incognito chrome tabs and connect as different users. Then you can see if the memory increases linearly to the number of users.